# Пейджер результатов

Tags: php, css

Здравствуйте, интересует, как можно изменить вывод страниц, а если точнее, привязать стили

```
 <?php
    class Navigator
    {
        function __construct($all,$pnumber,$query='')
        {
            $this->all=$all;
            $this->pnumber=$pnumber;
            $this->query=$query;
            $this->page=isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
        }

    function start()
    {
        $this->num_pages=ceil($this->all/$this->pnumber);

        if (isset($_GET['last']))
        $this->page=$this->num_pages;

        $this->start=$this->page*$this->pnumber-$this->pnumber;

        if ($this->page > $this->num_pages || $this->page < 1)
        {
            $this->page=1;
            $this->start=0;
        }

        return $this->start;
    }

    function navi()
    {

        if ($this->num_pages<2)
        return '';

        $buff='<div class="navigator">';

    for($pr = '', $i =1; $i <= $this->num_pages; $i++)
    {
        $buff.= 
        $pr=(($i == 1 || $i == $this->num_pages || abs($i-$this->page) < 2) ? ($i == $this->page ? " [$i] " : ' <a href="'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?module=adminuser&page='.$i.'&amp;'.$this->query.'">'.$i.'</a> ') : (($pr == ' ... ' || $pr == '')? '' : ' ... '));
    }
        return $buff.'</div>';
    }

}

/*$arr=range(1,100);

$n=new Navigator(100,5,'a=1');

echo $n->navi();*/
?>
```

вот код пейджера, вывод соответственно через echo $n->navi();

собственно как прикрутить этот вывод к css

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая практика - разделение логики и вывода....То есть выводить навигатор уже в шаблоне. Или сделать следующее:

```
    function navi($class="some_default_class")
{
```

А дальше в выводе сделать так:

```
$buff='<div class="navigator '.$class.'">';
```

Тогда, прописав стили для отдельных классов, вы сможете выводить навигацию по-разному...